# How to give to every item a different icon in a listactivity

Tags: android, listview, icons

I am new to android and I want to give to every item of my list activity a different icon so how can I do that...this is my list activity with the different items

```
public class MenuAct extends ListActivity {
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
   String[] values = new String[] { 
            "Mes Missions",
            "Mes Points",
            "Importer Geotiff",
            "Importer Point KML",
            "Importer Zone KML",
            "Exporter" };
    // use your custom layout
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        R.layout.menu_activity, R.id.label, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to create your own ListAdapter and then modify it to set the image.

Check out http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-listview-custom-adapter-with-imageview.html for an example.

Answer (score 0):

The adapter is responsible for creating the view associated to each item. In this case you're using `ArrayAdapter` which returns for each item a View consisting (more or less) of a single TextView with the string corresponding to each row.

What you need to do is to create a custom Adapter (derived from BaseAdapter) returning more complex views (in particular, including the ImageView you want).

This is a good sample: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown_custom

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a custom adapter. Within the adapter's getView() method, which you will override, you can easily put whatever icon you want on each item.

You can do this like so:

```
someListView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(mContext));
```

and then, if you keep your data in an ArrayList or similar (I called mine pathListThumbs), define ImageAdapter like this:

```
  public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return pathListThumbs.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
```

View itemView = convertView;
            if (gridView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                // get layout from xml
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylistviewitem, null);
            }

```
        final GridProductHolder holder;

        if (gridView.getTag() != null) {
            holder = (GridProductHolder) gridView.getTag();
        } else {
            holder = new GridProductHolder();
            gridView.setTag(holder);
            holder.thumbNail = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = pathListThumbs.get(position), wScale, hScale);


        if (bitmap != null) {
            holder.thumbNail.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's a snippet I used to adjust a camera image's size to desired x/y values:

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_FROM_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        _bitmapPreScale = gradeBookDbAdapter.getStudentPhoto(studentName);
    }
    if (_bitmapPreScale != null) {

            int oldWidth = _bitmapPreScale.getWidth();
            int oldHeight = _bitmapPreScale.getHeight();
            int newWidth = 200;  // whatever your desired width and height are
            int newHeight = 200;

            // calculate the scale
            float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / oldWidth;
            float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / oldHeight;

            // create a matrix for the manipulation
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            // resize the bit map
            matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

            // recreate the new Bitmap
            Bitmap _bitmapScaled = Bitmap.createBitmap(_bitmapPreScale, 0, 0,  oldWidth, oldHeight, matrix, true);


            // write the image back out so it's always small

            try {
                   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imgFile);
                   _bitmapScaled.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, out);
                   out.flush();
                   out.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                 Toast.makeText(mContext,"ERROR writing new image. Please try again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 Log.e("STUDENT", "ERROR WRITING");
                   e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
             Toast.makeText(mContext,"ERROR reading image. Please try again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             Log.e("STUDENT","ERROR READING");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

extend BaseAdapter, writing your own adpter

override getView, so you can set the images too

the getView of your adapter code should be something like (not tested)

```
@Override
public View getView(int index, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_activity, parent, false);

    TextView label = convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);

    label.setText(values[index]);

    Drawable icon = // obtain your image
    label.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(icon, null, null, null);
    return convertView;     
}
```